# MatLab: graphic not showing data

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I've tried to run this code in a Script in Matlab, but it's showing an empty graphic, with no data in it. I don't get any errors, either.

```
n = 0:0.1:5;
v = n*pi;

a1 = cos(2*n*pi/10);
a2 = cos(4*n*pi/10);
a = (-2.*a1-a2)/v;

b1 = sin(2*n*pi/10);
b2 = sin(4*n*pi/10);
b = (-2.*b1-b2)/(n*pi);

c = 3/5;

plot(a,'r')
hold on
plot(b,n,'b')

figure
plot3(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your element-wise operations are in the wrong place:

```
n = 0:0.1:5;
v = n*pi;

a1 = cos(2*n*pi/10);
a2 = cos(4*n*pi/10);
a = (-2*a1-a2)./v; % note the ./

b1 = sin(2*n*pi/10);
b2 = sin(4*n*pi/10);
b = (-2*b1-b2)./(n*pi); % note the ./

c = 3/5;

plot(a,'r')
hold on
plot(b,n,'b')

%figure
%plot3(a,b,c)
```

Your call to `plot3` is wrong because `c` is a scalar, it needs to be of the same dimension as `a` and `b` for the call to `plot3` to be valid.

Comment: well spotted. I think there is still an error in the call to `plot3` though since `c` is a single digit and `a` and `b` are both 1x51 vectors. Maybe the OP can enlighten us?

Comment: @Benoit_11 Yes, you're right, I have just realised this as well